# Mixed effects analysis - non-integer, not normally distributed data (R)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, robust

I'm working with a hierarchical design [Diagnosis(3 levels) -> donor(5 in 1 level, 3 in 2nd, and 8 in 3rd) -> Gender -> individuals], tested on different rounds for different measures (count data, duration data, ratio data). a sample of the data for R below. 
the goal is to test Diagnosis and control for different random effects according to:  `~ Diagnosis+(1|Donor)+(1|Round)+(1|Gender)` for each of the dependent variables (Also, if this is not the right way to do this, please let me know).

Problem is - my data is not normally distributed (nor are residuals from `lmer`) and neither log- nor Box-Cox transformations normalized it. Also, its not just count data (many non-integers; so `glmer` with `family=poisson` can only be used for one variable).

Stats are not my strong suite, although I'm trying hard to catch up. So far I know what doesn't work for my data.

Another option is to use robust statistics, with a package like `WRS2`, for mixed effects. To my understanding a 2-way ANOVA for medians (or trimmed means; in WRS2) is inappropriate. (also I keep getting an error trying to run it).

It is imperative for me that we do the appropriate analyses for these data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Round <- c(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)
ID <- c(17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32)
Gender <- c("Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male","Male")
Donor <- c("C1","C1","C1","C1","F3","F3","F3","F3","N7","N7","N7","N7","D3","D3","D3","D3")
Diagnosis <- c("N",'N',"N","N","A2","A2","A2","A2","N","N","N","N","A2","A2","A2","A2")
bur <- c(1,11,0,1,11,15,4,7,0,15,1,2,4,5,13,4)
dsi <- c(40.395,84.295,39.265,37.99,69.25,80.73,40.65,33.48,27.645,NA,23.35,27.05,58.565,33.225,88.26,102.525)
USV <- c(23.012,16.755,2.296,50.583,0.198,10.282,60.625,0.0022,21.012,29.067,41.932,40.114,2.489,9.989,5.569,22.999)
dat1 <- data.frame(Round,ID,Gender,Donor,Diagnosis,bur,dsi,USV)
View(dat1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalized Additive for Location, Scale and Shape would be your best choice. There are several distributions for discrete and continuous data.

In R, there is a package 'gamlss'. There are two functions to include random effects in the model: random() and re(). The first one allows the user to include random effects with exchangeable correlation structure as in the R-package lme4, while the second one allows the user to include random effects with a more complex correlation structure as in the R-package nlme. In particular, random() would be enough for your problem.

The main issue would be to choose the most appropriate distribution for each response variable. My suggestion is to start fitting the simplest distribution and increasing the complexity as it is needed. Perform the residual analysis is a crucial step. The functions plot() and wp() can help you.

In addition, the documentation is large: There are an [online book](http://www.gamlss.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Lancaster-booklet.pdf), [manual](http://www.gamlss.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/gamlss-manual.pdf), a [website](http://www.gamlss.org/) and so on.